# How to use checkboxes in react native for both android and IOS?

Tags: react-native, jsx

I have a modal with diffrent tabs in my app in which user can filter the search result with categories in the modal . right now it is working but I simply put an event on a `<TEXT>` , I need some visual clue like checkbox for my options

```
            {this.state.currentTab === 1 && (
              <View>                         
                <Text onPress={(text) => this.setGender(true)}>male</Text>
                <Text onPress={(text) => this.setGender(false)}>female</Text>
              </View>
            )}
```

How Can I use checkbox instead of `<TEXT>` to use both in android and IOS?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library for the checkbox 
" react-native-circle-checkbox "

```
import CircleCheckBox, {LABEL_POSITION} from 'react-native-circle-checkbox';

        {this.state.currentTab === 1 && (
                  <View>
                    <CircleCheckBox
              checked={true}
              onToggle={(text) => this.setGender(true)}
              labelPosition={LABEL_POSITION.RIGHT}
              label="MALE"
            />    
    <CircleCheckBox
              checked={true}
              onToggle={(text) => this.setGender(false)}
              labelPosition={LABEL_POSITION.RIGHT}
              label="FEMALE"
            />  
                  </View>
                )}
```

Example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/intrigued-marshmallows

Comment: How can I change checked to TRUE on change?

Comment: "checked" is based on true false flag so take that in state variable and on click change the state. ----------------checked={this.state.checked}
              onToggle={(text) => this.setGender(false)}
              labelPosition={LABEL_POSITION.RIGHT}
              label="FEMALE"
            />  

** Updated the example--->>>  https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/intrigued-marshmallows

Comment: I get error 500 , should I install it with yarn or I can simply just import it ?

Comment: This is the library link where you will get the configuration info --->>>>
https://github.com/ParamoshkinAndrew/ReactNativeCircleCheckbox

Comment: that is great , But if I have several checkboxes I can't toggle checked state for each one . It changes all at once . do you have a suggestion?

Comment: separate out the variables assigned to the checkboxes and on selecting change the specific variable value only by adding conditions
Updated the example--->>> snack.expo.io/@msbot01/intrigued-marshmallows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192137/discussion-between-hesam-sameni-and-pramod).

Answer (score 1):

Use This Component which I manually created. It renders same radio button on both platforms

```
const RenderRadio = (props) => {
  const {
     value, onChange, selectedValue
  } = props;
const checked = value === selectedValue;
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}
      onPress={() => onChange(value)}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          borderRadius: 10,
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderColor: '#002451',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            width: 10,
            height: 10,
            borderRadius: 5,
            backgroundColor: checked ? '#002451' : 'white',
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, marginLeft: 10 }}>{value}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

use it as

```
   <RenderRadio onChange={this.setSelectedValue} selectedValue={selectedValue} value={value}/>
```

and set Your selected value as

```
   setSelectedValue = (value) => {
     this.setState(selectedValue : value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use native-base library, that has more components which you can use for Search filters and this is more reliable, you can set it checked 
 using checked prop, that is boolean, like this :

```js
import {
  Icon,
  CheckBox,
  Spinner
} from "native-base";
 <TouchableOpacity   onPress={(text) => this.setGender(true)}       >
          <CheckBox checked ={tru}
            onPress={(text) => this.setGender(true)}                          />
  
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I get error 500 , should I install it with yarn or I can simply just import it ?

Comment: yes u should follow the steps https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-base and then should do react-native link, then you should be able to import it.